# Rails: Nested Forms and setting nested values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have created a nested form.  I have a model called contract and another called contract_details.  In my contract controller I have the following code:

```
def new
    @contract = Contract.new
    @contract.customer_id = params[:customer_id]
    7.times { 
      @contract.contract_details.build
      @contract.contract_details.del_day = "Sun"
    }
end
```

del_day is a column in my contract_details model but the following line of code is erring out:

```
@contract.contract_details.del_day = "Sun"
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I access a column in the nested model from the top controller.  Meaning, how do I set the value of a column in the contract_details model when building each row in the contracts controller?

Comment: Please add details on the error you are receiving and also what you are trying to achieve. Is contract_details an array/collection, or a single object?

Comment: Perhaps `@contract.contract_details` is an array. So when you build, you create probably last model in it.

Comment: I would suggest posting your models so we can see the assoiations

Comment: @zishe is right. `@contract.contract_details` is an array, and so it would it be incorrect to to `@contract.contract_details.del_day = "Sun"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I re-read, you would only be doing the same thing 7 times if it was an array, so suggest you try the following:

```
def new
    @contract = Contract.new
    @contract.customer_id = params[:customer_id]
    7.times { 
      @new_contract_details = @contract.contract_details.build
      @new_contract_details.del_day = "Sun"
    }
end
```

The issue would be that at present when you call the following line, there is no indication which of the 'contract_details' objects you are trying to update.

```
@contract.contract_details.del_day = "Sun"
```

Comment: Thank you.  Still new to rails so sometimes trying to get my head around things.  So, when rails does the @contract.contract_details.build, is that building an array then as other people have said?  If that is true could one also do the following:  @contract.contract_details[i].del_day = "Sun", as long as i was a loop?

Comment: Not exactly. In your model definition you most likely have 'has_many :contract_details' or similar. This specifies that you want a relationship with multiple entries. Behind the scenes this is represented by an ActiveRecord::Relation object. When you call .build on that relationship, it is creating a new contract_details object and setting the relationship from your contract object. You are correct in thinking that @contract.contract_details will return an array to you - use 'for i in 0..6' instead of '7.times' and you will get index i available in your loop.